# Filter array of objects based on another array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects with latitude and longitude stored like this and filter array of arrays containing latitudes and longitudes. I want to filter my data based on latitudes and longitudes.

```
var data = [{LatLng:[34.09755005, -118.2900766],all_time: 22, wait_list: 217}
{LatLng:[21.30799045, -157.853676],all_time: 23, wait_list: 210},
{LatLng:[36.0678305, -110.2900766],all_time: 19, wait_list: 237},
{LatLng:[26.0665546, -130.8946739],all_time: 15, wait_list: 307}
]
```

I have another array of arrays which I am using as filters

```
var nearest_array = [[21.30799045, -157.853676],[26.0665546, -130.8946739]]
```

The result array should be this--

```
var result_array = [{LatLng:[26.0665546, -130.8946739],all_time: 15, wait_list: 307},{LatLng:[21.30799045, -157.853676],all_time: 23, wait_list: 210}]
```

I tried  something but nothing seems to work--

```
data.filter(x => x.LatLng.some(g => nearest_array.includes(g)))

data.filter(x => nearest_array.includes(x.LatLng))
```

Comment: Does the output array need to by the reverse of the `nearest_array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `filter` and check for the `latitude` and `longitude` using the function `some`, this is for checking at least one object containing those coordinates.

```js
var data = [{LatLng:[34.09755005, -118.2900766],all_time: 22, wait_list: 217},{LatLng:[21.30799045, -157.853676],all_time: 23, wait_list: 210},{LatLng:[36.0678305, -110.2900766],all_time: 19, wait_list: 237},{LatLng:[26.0665546, -130.8946739],all_time: 15, wait_list: 307}],
    nearest_array = [[21.30799045, -157.853676],[26.0665546, -130.8946739]],
    result = data.filter(({LatLng: [lat, lon]}) => nearest_array.some(([ilat, ilon]) => lat === ilat && lon === ilon));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const data = [{ LatLng: [34.09755005, -118.2900766], all_time: 22, wait_list: 217 }, { LatLng: [21.30799045, -157.853676], all_time: 23, wait_list: 210 }, { LatLng: [36.0678305, -110.2900766], all_time: 19, wait_list: 237 }, { LatLng: [26.0665546, -130.8946739], all_time: 15, wait_list: 307 } ]
const filters = [ [21.30799045, -157.853676], [26.0665546, -130.8946739] ]

const result = data.filter(({LatLng}) => 
   filters.some(f => LatLng.every(l => f.includes(l))))

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to first filter the main array and inside of that filter to make sure that at least one of the `filters` has all of its elements matched in the `LatLng` array.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `filter`, you might `.map` from your `nearest_array`, and `.find` the associated `LatLng` item - `.map` is a bit more appropriate if your input array and output array are one-to-one:

```js
var data=[{LatLng:[34.09755005,-118.2900766],all_time:22,wait_list:217},{LatLng:[21.30799045,-157.853676],all_time:23,wait_list:210},{LatLng:[36.0678305,-110.2900766],all_time:19,wait_list:237},{LatLng:[26.0665546,-130.8946739],all_time:15,wait_list:307}];var nearest_array=[[21.30799045,-157.853676],[26.0665546,-130.8946739]]

const output = nearest_array.map((numsToFind) => {
  const joined = numsToFind.join(',');
  return data.find(({ LatLng }) => LatLng.join(',') === joined);
});
console.log(output);
```

(Non-primitives, like objects, arrays, and functions, are not equal to each other unless they reference the same item in memory - eg `[1, 2] !== [1, 2]` because there are *two separate arrays there*, each with a different place in memory. As a result, your `.includes` test won't work)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I really could not understand why it wasn't working even when I was trying to equate raw values. Your solution worked